# Android Open number keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I've an editBox whose property is set to `android:inputType="number"`. Now, if I exclusively touch the editBox, I get numberkeyboard. But when programatically I make focus, then qwerty keyboard appears.

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

shows the simple qwerty keyboard. What if I want to open the number keyboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(viewToEdit, 0);
```

To hide the keyboard:

```
if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: what you want to input?

Comment: I want to put a number zipcode. I've tried all, numbertype  properties in xml, etc. and to worsen, now the keyboard doesn't popup either!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
    yourEditText.performClick();
```